# Consume Twitter streaming API into database

Tags: twitter, backgroundworker, background-process, twitter-streaming-api

I want to consume a few keywords on the Twitter streaming API (they're low traffic, so performance is not a huge issue) and log each Tweet's JSON data into a database.  I want the service to run on my Dreamhost account (aka a shared hosting service).  The datastore will be a MySQL database.

Is there open source or a good code example that gets me most of the way there?  Overtime I might want to run some thin processing before doing the DB insert, but that's not a big deal initially.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to use CouchDB to store JSON data acquired from the stream? There is no need to perform any processing on the stream since the same thing can be achieved via views in CouchDB.

UPDATE:

I just did it. I got 14.3MB of data after database compaction while tracking "wimbledon" for the period of 30 mins :)

Comment: can you pls provide the sample code i can get started with..i am able to store timelines in couchdb

Answer (score 0):

I found using Phirehose (PHP implementation) the easiest to work with. They even have a path to for OAuth.

http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/wiki/UserStreams